# Protecting REST Token In Memory

Tags: c#, rest, token

So I have a REST api. I have a C# client which can log into it with username/password over https. It returns a token as a string. I store that token and then later when I make further API calls I can create an Authorization header:

client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

But the token is returned and stored in memory as a string. Doesn't this make it a security problem with the token being visible in a memory dump?

Comment: Seeming as you're sharing the token with the client, and the client can never be trusted, what's the security problem?

Comment: Well if the token was copied then couldn't it be used by hackers depending on the expiry time of the token?

Comment: Hypothetically - that makes this the same as the "session hijack attack" for which there are no easy solutions. That said, if the client computer has been compromised then it's far more likely (and easier) just to grab the unencrypted original credentials than to attempt a session-hijack. This isn't a problem worth worrying over. If evidence shows that this will be a real problem for your application then the best you can do is re-generate the token on every request (but watch out for client requests that arrive out-of-order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the person can read the memory on the computer, you've probably already lost any security you would have. They would be able to decompile your client to discover any mechanisms you use to obscure it and be able to reverse engineer them. Moreover, they'll likely be able to listen to network requests and get access to both the username/password and any token before you could do anything to secure it.

Your best bet to to assume that the token can be compromised. Make it time-limited and revocable in the event that it does fall into the wrong hands, at least then the damage can be limited.  You should also treat it like you would a username/password and limit the scope of access on your API based on who has been granted the token, not on the fact that access is made through your client.

Answer (score 0):

As tvanfosson said... if someone has access to the memory on the computer you've already lost.  That said... there are likely techniques you could use to beef up the security.  The oauth token is just an encrypted set of values.  You can likely encrypt the clients IP address in the token and validate the IP when the token is passed.

Comment: I accepted tvanfosson as my answer but I like your idea of embedding the IP address in there as well.